# What is the condition for a second degree equation to represent a parabola?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have an idea about the answer to this , but not the clarity .
Now the answer is $h^2=ab$ , if the equation is $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$
and that equation shouldn't be a pair of Straight lines.
But how does the proof go.
My attempt at it was take a line  $lx+my+n=0$ as the directrix and $(h,k)$ as the focus and apply $e=1$ , But when I compare the equations I got , I am getting more than the conditions stated above .
As there are three unknowns and three equations .
[image]

Comment: what happens when $b,h$ are both zero, but $a \neq 0 \; ? \; $

Comment: What happened, you lost interest in your question itself.

Answer (score 3):

The special case $h=b=0$ and $a\ne0$ leads to the standard equation of a parabola having its axis parallel to $y$ axis. In the general case the axis of the parabola will have a slope $m$ and all lines parallel to the axis intersect the parabola at a single point (this is a peculiar property of the parabola).

Substituting $y=mx+k$ (equation of a line parallel to the axis) into the general equation of a conic
$$
ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0
$$
we obtain
$$
(bm^2+2hm+a)x^2+2(bkm+fm+g+hk)x+bk^2+2fk+c=0.
$$
This equation can have a single solution for all values of $k$ only if the coefficient of $x^2$ vanishes, that is if:
$$
bm^2+2hm+a=0.
$$
For a parabola only a single value of $m$ is allowed, the slope of the axis, while in a hyperbola we have a single intersection for all lines parallel to either asymptote, hence two different values of $m$, and in an ellipse single intersections with all lines with a given slope are not possible. If the conic is a parabola, the discriminant of the above equation must then vanish, that is:
$$
h^2-ab=0.
$$
We get as a bonus the slope of the axis: $\displaystyle m=-{h\over b}$.

Answer (score 0):

For parabola $h^2=ab$ and $\Delta= abc+2fgh-af^2-bg^2-ch^2\ne 0$

Answer (score 0):

$y^2=4ax$  refers to the standard simple parabola where the axis $y=0$ is perpendicular to tan gent at vertex $x=0$. The length of latus rectum is $4a$.

So in a quadratic of $x,y$ if we can make perfect square and write it as $L_1^2=4AL_2$, where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are non parallel, it will be a parabola.

Hence, if we demand $$h^2=ab~~~~(1),$$ we can write
$$(x \sqrt{a}+y \sqrt{b} y)^2=-2gx-2fy-c \implies L_1=x\sqrt{a}+y \sqrt{b} y, L_2=-2gx-2fy-c.$$
The condition that $m_1 \ne m_2$ gives $$f \sqrt{a}- g \sqrt{b} \ne 0~~~(2)$$
(1) and (2) when put in the expression of $\Delta$ give us
$$\Delta=abc+2fgh-af^2-bg^2-ch^2=-[(f\sqrt{a}-g \sqrt{b}]^2 \ne 0~~~(3).$$

Normally, (1) and (3) are known to be necessary conditions for a parabola.
(1) and (2) though equivalent are often overlooked.